# message box in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, javascript

how to display the 'successfully saved' message box in asp.net web application by using javascript.

any idea ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of registering a some JavaScript code like this:

```
Response.write("<script>ShowMessage('Successfully saved !');</script>");
```

it is a bit cleaner to use this built-in method:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showMyMessage", "ShowMessage('Successfully saved!');", true);
```

This is a bit cleaner than using Response.Write and it automatically prepends and appends your code with '<script type="text/javascript">' and '</script>'.

In your ShowMessage(MyMessage) function you could do a simple alert() or you could do something like T.J. Crowder suggests.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

You can put arbitrary content on the page at just about any location by simply creating and appending absolutely-positioned DOM elements, see [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172194/how-to-pop-up-an-image-that-random-wanders-around-a-web-page-with-javascript/2172211#2172211) for details, but fundamentally:

```
var element;

element = document.createElement('div'); // Or whatever
element.style.position = "absolute";
element.style.left = "100px";
element.style.top = "100px";
element.style.width = "200px";
element.style.height = "200px";

document.body.appendChild(element);
```

The `left`, `top`, etc. can be any valid CSS values. You may also want to use `z-index` to ensure it appears on top of other content.

Of course, when they click on it or something you'll want to remove it:

```
document.removeChild(element);
```

If you want to "grey-out" the underlying page and such, you can use an [iframe shim](http://www.macridesweb.com/oltest/IframeShim.html) to achieve that.

#### Option 2

Another alternative is to use the JavaScript `alert` function, but it's pretty intrusive and old-fashioned looking.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert ( "Successfully saved" );
```

Display an alert dialog with the specified content and an OK button. See **[window.alert](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.alert)**

The problem with an alert box is that it blocks the user from any further action. Better if you can show custom messages in containers like `<span>` or `<div>` and place them in the page.

***Edit***

If you can use jQuery then this one has diferent sets of custom alert boxes.

**[jQuery impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php)**

Answer (score 0):

Response.write("<script>alert('Successfully saved !');</script>");

or call a javascript function which takes parameter
Response.write("<script>ShowMessage('Successfully saved !');</script>");

//client side function

function ShowMessage(message)
{
alert(message);
}

Comment: ya i know this , but it is showing me the warning image with the message.